# Why are Swift classes and structures set up the way they are?

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, struct, initialization

In Swift, classes have inheritance and structures don't. At the same time, class instances live in the heap while structure instances live on the stack.

This means that only two of four possibilities are allowed: You can have things that support inheritance and which live in the heap, or you can have things that do not support inheritance and which live on the stack. You *cannot* have things that support inheritance and which live on the stack, and you cannot have things which do not support inheritance and which live on the heap.

Why is this? What makes these latter two possibilities undesirable?

For an encore, why do structures get a free initializer, but classes don't?

Comment: "*you cannot have things which do not support inheritance and which live on the heap*" – yes you can, that's a `final class` you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable design regarding *value-type* vs. *reference-type*.

`Class` as a *reference-type*, its inheritance is corresponding to **identity**. while `Struct` as a *value-type* have no identity except for the value on top of the fields they contain, and thus can be freely copied. If you try to add sub-fields to a "inheriting struct", you change the fields, or values, of that struct, and there're no "is-a" relation between them anymore like `Class` inheritance, since it makes no sense to say that a *value-type* with fewer fields "is-a" another *value-type*.

The sub-fields added by the "inheriting struct" could be arbitrarily lost when copying (For example, C++ invoked copy constructors when it happened) and make characteristics like *compatibility* lose their significance. `Class` on the other hand don't have these problems, since each instance of a `Class` has a unique identity, and only references to that instance are passed around.

Let's take a point on a 2D-plane, which is a `Struct` containing two fields: `x` and `y`, for example. Said there's another sub-struct which represented a point on a 3D-world, which had a sub-field `z`.

When we do like:

```
point2D = point3D;
```

What should happen on the assignment line then? since the memory occupied by the `point2D` is already fixed?

As of your question, it's directly related to the characteristics of heap and stack themselves, when a program entered a function, or a local variable is allocated, they are pushed onto the current stack frame, which is of fixed size, and are poped/deallocated later as the function is exited, this makes it relatively easier to be optimized for the CPU.

The heap, on the other hand, had additional complexity since programmers are able to directly interact with it with commands like `malloc` or `free` - resulting in additional request and release times - which had more cost of time; they may require additional memory upon initialization - for the fields that may or may not contain value at the beginning - which had more cost of spaces, etc. Messing these characteristics up would just make optimization more complicated.